# Microservice: Cross Service Validation and Decoupling?

Tags: spring-boot, architecture, apache-kafka, microservices, spring-cloud-netflix

Let's imagine I have a Vehicle Service and a Booking Service (using a classic Spring Boot, Eureka, Zuul stack).

When I want to book a vehicle, if I want to validate for example that the vehicle exists, is there is a better way to do that than by calling the Vehicle Service from the Booking Service ?

I would like the application to remain decoupled.

I was thinking I could have a Facade microservice that could do this check but is there a better way to do that?

is there any pattern for validation that can ensure decoupling, or should I just forget about validating such data?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. You have to make a call to vehicle service to check if vehicle exist. 
There is no tech solution here. You have a vehicle service, which knows about vehicle and booking service that deals with booking. But resource you are booking needs to be validate by the owner of that resource.

You may think of caching information related to vehicle in booking service but I will advice you against it.

However, you may have biz solution around it.
Some one would have called a booking service and would have passed vehicle info alongside.
Now your vehicle service can share vehicle info along side two set of fields. InventoryIssueTimestamp and InventoryExpiryTimestamp. you pretty much saying when someone is booking i let them have inventory for n minutes. If booking is done within n minutes you are good else you make a status check.

There could be similar ways you can think around. But these are more likely be an over engineering, unless you have some very specific use cases. It is mostly clean to make a validation call. Only reason i have tried to explain this scenario to make you think outside tech based solution.

Comment: in fact I'm looking for the best way to avoid to have too much cross relations between services, like to avoid to end up with a "spaghetti plate".

Comment: with microservices, you cannot avoid it. Each service is doing things related to its domain. But for cross cutting concerns, you would have to make api calls (or any open any other mode of communication). Downside is that if not done correctly you will making calls left right and centre, but it boils down to how you have managed the external api calls. this could be putting all external calls under one package, offloading as much as possible onto queues (As it takes dependency outside your service), but there is no silver bullet. Opt for whats fits your bill be it tech or biz logic.